# Google Analytics Reporting api for Universal analytics throws Unknown name \"dimensionName\" error

Tags: php, laravel, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to use the Google API to get data from my website, but I have an error that happens whenever I try to use the "DimensionsFilters" option, for some reason it returns an error saying that the JSON format is invalid, I've tried in many ways but always the error..

```
$metrics = [           
            'pageviews',           
        ];
        // Create the DateRange object.
        $dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
        $dateRange->setStartDate("2022-12-01");
        $dateRange->setEndDate("2023-01-19");

        // Create the Metrics object.
        $dataMetrics = [];

        foreach ($metrics as $metric) {
            $sessions = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
            $sessions->setExpression("ga:" . $metric);
            $sessions->setAlias($metric);
            $dataMetrics[] = $sessions;
        }

        //filter
        // [ ['dimension_name']=>['sourceMedium'] , 'operator'=>'EXACT' , 'expressions'=>['my_campaign']
        $dimensionFilter = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DimensionFilter();
        $dimensionFilter->setDimensionName("ga:pagePath");
        $dimensionFilter->setOperator('BEGINS_WITH');
        $dimensionFilter->setExpressions(['/u/joao?preview=614']);

        $dimensionFilterClause = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DimensionFilterClause;
        $dimensionFilterClause->setFilters([$dimensionFilter]);
        $dimensionFilterClause->setOperator('AND');

        //Create the Dimensions object.
        $pageUrl = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
        $pageUrl->setName("ga:pagePath");

        // Create the ReportRequest object.
        $request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
        // dd($request);
        $request->setViewId("ga:203877"); //test rise
        $request->setMetrics($dataMetrics); // METRIC
        $request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
        $request->setDimensions([$pageUrl]);
        $request->setDimensionFilterClauses([$dimensionFilter]);

        $body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
        $body->setReportRequests([$request]);

        return ($this->analytics->reports->batchGet($body)->getReports());
```

RESPONSE ERROR:

```
{ "error": { "code": 400, "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"dimensionName\" at 'report_requests[0].dimension_filter_clauses[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"expressions\" at 'report_requests[0].dimension_filter_clauses[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid value at 'report_requests[0].dimension_filter_clauses[0].operator' (type.googleapis.com/google.analytics.reporting.v4.FilterLogicalOperator), \"BEGINS_WITH\"", "errors": [ { "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"dimensionName\" at 'report_requests[0].dimension_filter_clauses[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"expressions\" at 'report_requests[0].dimension_filter_clauses[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid value at 'report_requests[0].dimension_filter_clauses[0].operator' (type.googleapis.com/google.analytics.reporting.v4.FilterLogicalOperator), \"BEGINS_WITH\"", "reason": "invalid" } ], "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT", "details": [ { "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest", "fieldViolations": [ { "field": "report_requests[0].dimension_filter_clauses[0]", "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"dimensionName\" at 'report_requests[0].dimension_filter_clauses[0]': Cannot find field." }, { "field": "report_requests[0].dimension_filter_clauses[0]", "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"expressions\" at 'report_requests[0].dimension_filter_clauses[0]': Cannot find field." }, { "field": "report_requests[0].dimension_filter_clauses[0].operator", "description": "Invalid value at 'report_requests[0].dimension_filter_clauses[0].operator' (type.googleapis.com/google.analytics.reporting.v4.FilterLogicalOperator), \"BEGINS_WITH\"" } ] } ] } }
```

Comment: `$dataRange` should also be in an array see: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/samples#php_4  maybe you have more little issues.

Comment: @Foobar it's not because of that. If i removed the line ```        $request->setDimensionFilterClauses([$dimensionFilter]);
``` my code works. The problem is DimensionFilters.

Comment: I have edited your title to make it clear you are using UA analytics and not GA4

Comment: @DaImTo thanks, but I have use the v4 its not de GA4? I thought it was, but thanks anyway.

Comment: To connect to Google analytics GA4 accounts you use the [Google Analytics Data api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1).   The [Google analytics reporting api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/) which you are currently using will only gain you access to Universal analytics accounts.

Comment: U set, but don't use `$dimensionFilterClause` later, is that right?

Comment: @Foobar I dont belive.. It was the problem.

Comment: Better check complex code often as you can. I saw this, after you telled me about the remove of the line. :-)